# how to generate random variables from a beta distribution in the fixed interval

Tags: python, intervals, truncated, beta-distribution

I have to use python to use Gibbs sampler to sample from posterior full conditional distribution.However, the posterior full conditional distribution is like this:

[image]

a beta distribution but in the interval instead the [0,1] which is a beta range

Comment: Are you talking about the [beta prime distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beta_prime_distribution) by any chance?

Comment: What is the function `I` in that picture? If it's a "boolean test" outputting 0 or 1, then the usual beta distribution (i.e. defined only for [0,1]) makes sense there.